# Expansion panel is not expanding in kivymd

Tags: kivy, python-3.7, kivy-language, expansion

My MDExpansionPanel in kivymd is not expanding I have written that code in .kv file

here's my .py file

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class TtApp(MDApp):
    pass


TtApp().run()
```

and here's my .kv file

```
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        MDExpansionPanelTwoLine:
            text: ''
            secondary_text: 'email: xxxxx@gmail.com'

            IconLeftWidget:
                icon: "email"

        TwoLineAvatarListItem:
            text: ''
            secondary_text: 'to: @gmail.com'

            IconLeftWidget:
                icon: "email"
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work, I think mirroring the way you had it set up.

It seems that you have to build `MDExpansionPanel` via Python rather than KV language. Also, you have to define `content` and `panel_cls` for the `MDExpansionPanel` object.

Here is you new `main.py`:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.expansionpanel import MDExpansionPanel, MDExpansionPanelTwoLine
from kivymd import images_path


class Content(MDBoxLayout):
    pass


class TtApp(MDApp):

    def on_start(self):
        self.root.ids.box.add_widget(
            MDExpansionPanel(
                icon=f"{images_path}folder.png", # need an email .png here
                content=Content(),
                panel_cls=MDExpansionPanelTwoLine(
                    text='',
                    secondary_text='email: xxxxx@gmail.com',
                )
            )
        )


TtApp().run()
```

Here is your new tt.kv:

```
<Content>:
    adaptive_height: True

    TwoLineAvatarListItem:
        text: ''
        secondary_text: 'to: @gmail.com'

        IconLeftWidget:
            icon: "email"

Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        id: box
```

Comment: I know this but I want all of it in my tt.kv file how can I do that

Comment: I think it's not possible. I don't remember the error message, but when I attempted the same thing in KV language, it complained about `panel_cls`. The [official example code for MDExpansionPanel](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/expansion-panel/index.html#example) uses Python rather than KV, and I was unable to find a single example on the web of `panel_cls` defined in KV.